# :first-child affecting other child elements

Tags: css, sass

I have this in my SASS file:

```
.buttons {
    :first-child {
        padding-top:7px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      bla blaa
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="advance">Step2</a>
    <button class="btn">help <i class="arrow"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The arrow child is being affected by the `padding`, though. I just want the first child inside the parent `.button`.

I have also tried this:

```
.buttons {
    &:first-child {
        padding-top:5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first solution:

```
.buttons {
    :first-child {
        padding-top: 7px;
    }
 }
```

Essentially turns into this rule:

```
.buttons *:first-child { padding-top: 7px; }
```

This is going to have exactly the effect you're describing - every `:first-child` in the hierarchy under `.buttons` is going to be affected.

Your second solution:

```
.buttons {
    &:first-child {
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

Turns into this rule:

```
.buttons:first-child { padding-top: 5px; }
```

This is going to only affect `.buttons` itself, and only if it is the `:first-child` within it's parent.

What I *think* you are looking for is:

```
.buttons > *:first-child { padding-top: 5px; }
```

This will affect the first element, regardless of type, which exists within `.buttons`.

Comment: .buttons > *:first-child { padding-top: 5px; } This is causing render error invalid

Comment: I'm sorry Troy my fault I added something else that was causing the error. This worked thank you. Can you explain what > is doing in sass I never used it before. Also I guess the * is just saying any element type. so I could use  > div:first-child{} to get to the first div inside .buttons

Comment: Yes, `*` in CSS means "any element type". And `>` in CSS means "a direct descendant". In other words, `div > span` would match `<div><span>this</span></div>` but not `<div><p><span>this</span></p></div>`